# Are function pointers thread safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

(This follows [Are static inline functions thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125761/are-static-inline-functions-thread-safe))

Scenario: I have written a big piece of code, running on 2 parallel threads, which are identical in term of code and just process different data. I am seeing non-deterministic results. If I disable one of the 2 threads, the results become deterministic. Within this code I am using some function pointers, and I would like to understand if they could be a possible cause of my problem.

Are function pointers thread-safe in C? Said the other way around, if they have no static variable inside, but only some local variables and the input parameters, will a simultaneous call from the 2 threads cause unpredictable behaviour?

Example code:

```
void foo(int param1, int* out);
void bar(int param1, int* out);

typedef void (*fooBarFuncP_t)(int, int*);

static inline fooBarFuncP_t getFooBar(int selection) {
    switch (selection) {
        case 0:
            return &foo;
        case 1:
        default:
            return &bar;
    }
}

void test(int selection, int x, int* y) {
    (*getFooBar(selection))(x,y);
}
```

Where:

- In their implementation, `foo` and `bar` have only local, non static variables
- `y` is allocated separately for the 2 threads by the caller of test

Is this thread-safe? If not, what solutions exist for this problem?

Comment: There is no data race here.

Comment: So there is no interaction possible between `foo` and `bar`, right? At first sight I don't see any problems here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Good point. `foo` and `bar` share some buffer (it is part of the input parameters). But the buffers are allocated separately for the 2 threads, and `foo` and `bar` are never called at the same time *within the same thread*. (I am double checking)

Comment: @Antonio Well then they don't share the buffer.

Comment: The code either has a bug, or you are holding unwarranted assumptions, or both.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here... Function pointers, like any variables, may or may not be thread-safe. If they are written to by one thread while another thread uses the same variable, they need to be protected. As for whether the function called by a function pointer is thread-safe or not, that entirely depends on the implementation of that function. It has nothing to do with the function pointer itself.

Comment: @Lundin Despite having a simple answer (there's no difference between a normal function call and a function call through its pointer), the question is very clear.

Comment: @Antonio Perhaps it would be if you could clarify if the question is about thread safety of function pointers, or thread safety of functions called by function pointers.

Comment: @Lundin I guess both are relevant, especially the second I would say

Comment: The thread callback functions themselves are called through function pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling/using function pointer is no different to a using a function with respect to thread-safety.
In the example, you posted there's no thread-safety issues (under the conditions you have stated).

Assuming you still have problems related to thread-safety, some suggestions:

- Check if there's any data race in your code.
- Check if there are any static variables involved through headers, library functions, third-party functions etc (I know you have said none but still it's possible you missed some).
- Run your code under [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between function pointers and regular variables in terms of thread-safety. If a variable is shared by several threads and at least on thread writes to the variable, you need to protect it.

Where a function is called from has no relevance for that function's thread-safety. The only thing that matters is which thread that executes the function. If several threads call the same function, no matter how they do it, then that function needs to be thread-safe.

Comment: Isn't it that the function according to my example is thread safe? (See also notes under it)

Comment: @Antonio The "test" function does nothing with shared resources so there is no reason why it would be unsafe. Whether that example is thread-safe or not only depends on if the two called functions are thread-safe.